# Get rid of (or raise) the flag limit for reviewers

Tags: feature-request, review, flags

First of all, I know I *only* have 500 reputation points on SO, and I'm *new* to the reviewers team. **Yes.** But maybe the best ideas can come when you are new, no?

Anyways, as I said I'm new to reviewing, but what bothers me a lot is the **flag limit** (11 flags per day). This limit is good to apply to regular users without queue permission (so users with less than 500 rep points), I never reached it without the queues, there are not only bad posts after all.

But the problem is when we get a reviewing queue! I will be talking of the *Triage* queue, as it's the most important for my arguments.
Posts in this reviewing queue are **much more** subject to be FLAGGED, so of course, you can easily reach this limit.

And once you reached this limit? Well, you cannot really review posts anymore, you can't flag them if needed. I will take a concrete example at the time I'm writing this. I just reviewed the **full** "Late Answers" queue, and had to use 6 of my flags, on 20 answers. Then I started reviewing the "Triage" queue, and used my 5 remaining flags. I don't have any more flag, but can still review 20 questions (limit is 40 because the queue is quite full atm). Then I encounter this post: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/28366950. What can I do? Nothing, I can't flag it anymore, and I have to press "Skip".

This case is even worse, because a 47k+ user edited it (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66287545/revisions)... But WHY, **yes**, this user used words to bypass the filter, but in that case, the post should have been **deleted**.

Anyways, let me know if you guys agree with this.
*Also yes, this has already been raised but it was in 2009 when no one even had 1000 all-time revisions.*

Comment: I am not entirely sure why this is getting downvoted into oblivion.  I agree that the queues are much more likely to be flagged and 11 per day is a relatively meager number.    While I can understand the accepted answer, the question and point of view seems valid to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please relax and keep on flagging. You'll get more flags per day eventually, even more than you can use in *multiple* review queues:

> #### How many flags do I have?
>
> When you start out, you are allotted 10 flags per day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts))

Comment: Oh I didn't know about this, ok. Though, my flags are sometimes denied but they should actually be accepted, so I'm confused. (I can give a link to an answer I flagged and has been falsely denied for me if you want) EDIT: I actually have 3 denied flags from queue, and cannot understand why, maybe you could explain? Maybe there's another place to discuss about this?

Comment: @Gugu72 Meta Stack Overflow (or the meta site for the specific site you're using) would be better than this site, which is a network-wide meta.

Comment: @Gugu72, as a hack / workaround, consider reviewing close to midnight SE time; then your continuous block of time would encompass two SE "days".